# spark sbt compile error libraryDependencies

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, sbt-assembly

`1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4` and my Scala version is `2.11.7`. I am getting an error so I can't use sbt.

```
~/sparksample$ sbt
```

`Starting sbt: invoke with -help for other options [info] Set current project to Spark Sample (in build file:/home/beyhan/sparksample/)`

```
> sbt compile
```

`[info] Updating {file:/home/beyhan/sparksample/}default-f390c8... [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.7 ... [info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11.7;1.2.0 ... [warn]  module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11.7;1.2.0 [warn] ==== local: tried [warn]   /home/beyhan/.ivy2/local/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11.7/1.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml [warn] ==== public: tried [warn]   http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11.7/1.2.0/spark-core_2.11.7-1.2.0.pom [warn]    :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   ::      UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         :: [warn]   :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [warn]   :: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11.7;1.2.0: not found [warn]   :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: [error] {file:/home/beyhan/sparksample/}default-f390c8/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11.7;1.2.0: not found [error] Total time: 2 s, completed Oct 15, 2015 11:30:47 AM`

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: Can you share your `build.sbt` and maybe the other sbt files?

Comment: name := "Spark Sample"

version := "1.2.0"
 
scalaVersion := "2.11.7"
 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11.7" % "1.2.0"   Hocam bu dosya var ama bununla sparkın kendi bulunduğu dosya konumları farklı yerlerde.sıkıntı olur mu ?

Comment: `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11.7" % "1.2.0"` should either be `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.2.0"` or `libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"`. There is no such thing as *spark path* here, as this dependency is required to build, not only to run, the spark app. Also, community rules strongly enforce you to ask/answer/comment in English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There exists no `spark-core_2.11.7` jar file. You have to get rid of the maintenance version number `.7` in the spark dependencies because `spark-core_2.11` exists. All Scala versions with version `2.11` should be compatible.

#### Update

A minimal sbt file could look like

```
name := "Simple Project"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.5.1"
```

Comment: unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-compiler;2.11: not found
unresolved dependency: org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11: not found
Error during sbt execution: Error retrieving required libraries
  (see /home/beyhan/.sbt/boot/update.log for complete log)
[error] {file:/home/beyhan/sparksample/}default-f390c8/*:scala-instance: xsbti.RetrieveException: Could not retrieve Scala 2.11
[error] Total time: 4 s, completed Oct 15, 2015 12:01:45 PM   Error is change but i think same error :/

Comment: For the Scala compiler you should keep the maintenance version number. Thus, your dependencies should look like `scala-compiler;2.11.7` and `spark-core_2.11;1.2.0`.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include a minimal sbt file which should do the job.

Comment: hmm where should i put the jar file and this sbt file ? i am getting same error  update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11.7;1.2: not found

Comment: Simply put the sbt file in the root directory of your project. The dependency should be automatically downloaded by sbt.

Answer (score 1):

As @Till Rohrmann suggested you there's no such thing as `spark-core_2.11.7` and your build.sbt appears to reference that library.

I suggest you to edit the file `/home/beyhan/sparksample/build.sbt` and remove the references to that library.

The correct reference is:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.2.0"
```

Remember that not only `spark-core` does not have any version `2.11.7` but also other spark libraries that you might be using.

Answer (score 0):

[info] Updating {file:/home/beyhan/sparksample/}default-f390c8... [info] Resolving org.scala-lang#scala-library;2.11.7 ... [info] Resolving org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11.7;1.2.0 ... [warn] module not found: org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11.7;1.2.0 [warn] ==== local: tried [warn]
/home/beyhan/.ivy2/local/org.apache.spark/spark-core_2.11.7/1.2.0/ivys/ivy.xml [warn] ==== public: tried [warn]