# Error about sbt yarn at using spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, sbt, hadoop-yarn, sbt-assembly

hi when i am writing this code

```
>sbt
```

And after seeing this result

```
beyhan@beyhan:~/sparksample$ sbt
Starting sbt: invoke with -help for other options
[info] Set current project to Spark Sample (in build file:/home/beyhan/sparksample/)
```

And after i am writing this code

```
>compile
```

And i am getting this error

```
[error] {file:/home/beyhan/sparksample/}default-f390c8/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-common;1.0.4: not found
    [error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-client;1.0.4: not found
    [error] unresolved dependency: org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-api;1.0.4: not found
    [error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.transaction;1.1.1.v201105210645!javax.transaction.orbit
    [error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.servlet;3.0.0.v201112011016!javax.servlet.orbit
    [error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.mail.glassfish;1.4.1.v201005082020!javax.mail.glassfish.orbit
    [error] download failed: org.eclipse.jetty.orbit#javax.activation;1.1.0.v201105071233!javax.activation.orbit
    [error] Total time: 14 s, completed Oct 16, 2015 3:58:48 PM
```

My sparksample has this.

```
beyhan@beyhan:~/sparksample$ ll
total 20
drwxrwxr-x  4 beyhan beyhan 4096 Eki 16 16:02 ./
drwxr-xr-x 57 beyhan beyhan 4096 Eki 16 15:27 ../
drwxrwxr-x  2 beyhan beyhan 4096 Eki 16 16:02 project/
-rw-rw-r--  1 beyhan beyhan  142 Eki 15 18:57 simple.sbt
drwxrwxr-x  3 beyhan beyhan 4096 Eki 15 11:14 src/
```

Also src file has

```
src>main>scala>SimpleCode.scala
```

And my simple.sbt file like this

```
name := "Spark Sample"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "1.2.0"
```

What should i do?
I think this error about my yarn because i don't have.
Thanks.

Comment: Your .sbt file should be called build.sbt. I think you are missing a dependency. Try to add libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hadoop" %% "hadoop-yarn-common" % "1.0.4" to this file.

Comment: why 1.0.4 ? and i think my sbt file is correct because i can connect and also i don't have hadoop-yarn

Comment: Because that's the version from the error message. Obviously, you need hadoop yarn. But this is what sbt solves for you. You just have to list it as dependecy. Btw.: Sbt has a default mode, working even when no build file is present. Just rename it, it's called build.sbt by convention.

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33143665/spark-sbt-compile-error-librarydependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This dependency of `org.apache.hadoop#hadoop-yarn-client;1.0.4` for you doesn't seem like it is because of `build.sbt`. Perhaps there is something wrong with your cached files in `~/.ivy2` or `~/.m2`, or maybe because of some `project/*.sbt` files introducing additional dependencies.

It works fine for me though:

`build.sbt`

```
$ cat build.sbt 
name := "Spark Sample"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.7"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "1.2.0"
```

All dependencies resolved:

`$ sbt compile
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.9 ...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-app
    confs: [default]
    52 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (17785kB/791ms)
Getting Scala 2.10.5 (for sbt)...
:: retrieving :: org.scala-sbt#boot-scala
    confs: [default]
    5 artifacts copied, 0 already retrieved (24493kB/306ms)
[info] Set current project to Spark Sample (in build file:/home/tuxdna/tmp/p/)
[info] Updating {file:/home/tuxdna/tmp/p/}p...
[info] Resolving jline#jline;2.12.1 ...
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-core_2.11/1.2.0/spark-core_2.11-1.2.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.spark#spark-core_2.11;1.2.0!spark-core_2.11.jar (31007ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-network-common_2.11/1.2.0/spark-network-common_2.11-1.2.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.spark#spark-network-common_2.11;1.2.0!spark-network-common_2.11.jar (1873ms)
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/spark/spark-network-shuffle_2.11/1.2.0/spark-network-shuffle_2.11-1.2.0.jar ...
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.apache.spark#spark-network-shuffle_2.11;1.2.0!spark-network-shuffle_2.11.jar (2122ms)
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 61 s, completed 17 Oct, 2015 12:48:49 AM`

Note my installed Scala and SBT versions:

```
$ sbt sbt-version
[info] Set current project to Spark Sample (in build file:/home/tuxdna/tmp/p/)
[info] 0.13.9
$ scala -version
Scala code runner version 2.11.2 -- Copyright 2002-2013, LAMP/EPFL
```

Could you try these steps using a separate user ( or maybe on a separate machine ) ?